# Finding the top ten highest digits in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display the top ten highest priced boats saved to my database.

My sailboats table looks like this

```
class CreateSailboats < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :sailboats do |t|
   t.string :brand
   t.string :model
   t.text :description
   t.string :condition
   t.string :title
   t.decimal :price, default: 0

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

I don't have anything else in my views, controller, or model because I have no clue where to start or what to do.

Comment: You might find [this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+find+top+ten+records) helpful.

Comment: Yes, order by the price column then fetch the last or first ten.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do what you're trying to accomplish.

```
Sailboat.all(price: :desc, :limit=>10)
```

Also, you should take a look at this guide on Rails Guides:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#read

Comment: Yup it works now and the link you gave helped as well

Comment: Great, then do you mind marking it correct if it resolved the problem?

Comment: @K-Log You might consider changing your answer to Sailboat.all(price: :desc,:limit=>10).

Comment: Updated! Thanks for he feedback.